# Django: Creating permissions that relate two `User` objects together

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to set up a permissions system where permissions relate `User` objects together, i.e. where one `User` may have the permission to read another `User`'s info (but not necessarily the other way around)? I've read the documentation but it's sparse and from what I can tell permissions are not capable of handling dynamic use-cases.

Basically, I want a permission system that determines what two+ model objects can "do" to each other.

Bonus points if you have any input on how to integrate this into Django Rest Framework.

Comment: How do you determine this access? Based on some field in DB?

Comment: @a_k_v that's one possibility, but I'm open to suggestions. I'd like to leverage Django's existing permissions framework, but if that's not possible I can roll out my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to override the BasePermission class to create your custom permission. You can specify the access permission using an extra field in the User model.

```
class UserPermission(BasePermission):   

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_allowed_user = False
        try:
            permission = Permission.objects.get(user=request.user.id, user1=request.GET.get('user'))
            if permission.is_read_enabled:
                is_allowed_user = True
            else
                is_allowed_user = False
        except Permission.DoesNotExist as e:
            is_allowed_user = False        
        return is_allowed_user
```

Create a model to specify the Permissions

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
    is_read_enabled = models.BooleanField(defualt=False)
```

Add this permission to view as needed.